# I have to create a mobile app (Android) that print to screen some data received by bluetooth

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I have to create an app android that can read data from bluetooth and show it on screen

I've always tried to connect device to bluetooth. But after this I have not idea of how to read data.

Comment: so basically, you tried something that may, or may not, have worked, an now you have no idea how to continue...

Comment: I managed to get only to the pairing between devices, but I do not know how the communication works, especially the data reading

Comment: The basic idea is after getting paired.Get the inpupt/output streams then make the data transfer

Comment: Yes, I thought that. But I don't now how to dot that. Have you got any ideas?